# Lazy loading via AJAX - JS templating or HTML from server

Tags: ajax, lazy-loading

I am a little new to development so apologies if this question is trivial. I am trying to implement lazy loading by sending an AJAX call to my server, querying the database and returning the next batch of data to be displayed. Is there any advantage of sending JSON back as response to AJAX call, and then using a templating engine like mutache.js v/s sending straight HTML from the server. Couple of people have warned me against sending HTML but I don't understand the de-merits of doing so. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

By sending only the data to the client you off-load the HTML rendering from the server to the client. This means more CPU cycles and bandwidth to serve other HTTP requests.

I have had pleasure in using ember.js to accomplish these tasks on the client side, with a django app on the server providing the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the both ways.

Sending HTML is faster for your user. But you can not reuse rendered data and have to reload pieces of HTML each time. This might be ok. People have used this approach for many years and I believe that this is still the most popular approach. HTML approach works!

You might need to think about protection from injections of malicious javascript in HTML.

If you have JSON-based communication protocol you can create more difficult javascript client. If is more reusable with other types of clients. It requires more time to render HTML from JSON (but you can save more time by re-using JSON data). Also, use plain JSON, not JS and you will have more secure application.